# Proof in the realm of $\infty$ categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories, triangulated-categories

I have recently started learning the language of $\infty$-categories. My approach is more to their use, rather than for their own sake. For this reason, as I feel I reached a good understanding of the basic notions (the definition, functors, adjoints, stable categories, etc.), I have now turned my attention to some papers which work in the framework of stable $\infty$-categories to solve the functoriality issues we encounter when we work with triangulated categories. However, I am having problems understanding what can be proved and what can't using techniques similar to the triangulated world. For example, I am reading *Noncommutative homological projective duality* by Alexander Perry ([arXiv:1804.00132](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00132)), and in the first part some results about $S$-linear categories (where $S$ is a scheme satisfying some assumptions) are proved. The formal definition is that the categories of $S$-linear categories is the categories of module objects $\text{Mod}_{\mathfrak{Perf}(S)}(\text{Cat}_{\text{st}})$, where $\text{Cat}_{\text{st}}$ is the $\infty$-category of stable, idempotent complete $\infty$-categories with exact functors. The author then wants to prove that if we have an $S$-linear functor $\phi : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ between $S$-linear categories which has a left adjoint when considered as a plain functor of $\infty$-categories, then $\phi^{L}$ is automatically an $S$-linear functor. The proof which is given in the paper uses the internal hom for $S$-linear categories, and the adjunction properties
$$
\mathcal{H}om_{S}(\phi^L(C \otimes F), D) \simeq \mathcal{H}om_{S}(C \otimes F, \phi(D)) \simeq \mathcal{H}om_S(C, \phi(D) \otimes F^{\vee}) \simeq \dots \mathcal{H}om_S(\phi^{L}(C) \otimes F,D)
$$
where $C \in \mathcal{C}, D \in \mathcal{D}, F \in \mathfrak{Perf}(S)$, and $\otimes$ denotes the module structure. Then the proof is concluded using the Yoneda lemma.
This is the proof I would write if I were working in the triangulated setting, and I don't understand why one is allowed to use it in the $\infty$-categorical framework as well. Adjunction in this case as far more tricky (even if they imply the obvious isomorphism on mapping spaces), and the structure of $S$-linear functor implies $\phi^L(C \otimes F) \simeq \phi^L(C) \otimes F$ up to contractible choices, but it is not equivalent to this isomorphism, is it? It would be very helpful is some could help me understanding to which point one can transport proofs from the triangulated world to the stable $\infty$-categorical framework. Thanks.

Comment: That proof doesn't give the full details, but it doesn't do so in the 1-categorical world either: being S-linear is additional *structure* on a functor, not just a property. However, for the left adjoint of an S-linear functor you have canonical oplax structure maps $\phi^L(C \otimes F) \rightarrow \phi^L(C) \otimes F$ (adjoint to the map $C \otimes F \rightarrow \phi\phi^L(C) \otimes F \simeq \phi(\phi^L(C) \otimes F)$ defined by the unit of the adjunction and the linearity of $\phi$). So what you're really showing is that this particular map is an equivalence.

Comment: The same is true in the $\infty$-categorical setting, it's just a bit trickier to set up the oplax structure maps in a coherent way. In this particular case (and many others) this is best dealt with using cocartesian fibrations (for the details see Corollary 7.3.2.12 in Higher Algebra).

Comment: Ok, I see, so we're taking that map and we are showing that it is an equivalence, thus getting the linearity. I know the following might be a too broad question to answer, or it might be nonsense, but how many of these details are generally swept under the rug? Because most of the papers I came across prove these statements as they were in the triangulated world, which probably means there is something behind which ensure things can't be so bad.

Comment: This illustrates a common feature of working with $\infty$-categories: if you're checking a property you can often reason just as in the 1-categorical setting, but to obtain structures you usually have to figure out a canonical reason why they exist (though this can often give cleaner proofs for 1-categories too than you get by writing them out explicitly).

Comment: I see, thank you for your clear answers!

Comment: @Federico My impression is that many details are swept under the rug in the triangulated world as well, it's just that some people feel more confident in doing so in that setup (although it's not really clear to me why...)

Comment: @Dennis You're probably right, it might be because triangulated categories have been around for longer, and people are more accostumed to their subtleties. I'm finding the framework of $\infty$-categories hard to get into because there is a huge amount of things one needs to know (even finding your way through the many references to Lurie's books sometimes isn't easy).

Comment: @Denis Unfortunately that is true.  However one difference that is relevant to me (an outsider) is that claims in the triangulated setting are often strictly weaker, since all issues of homotopy coherence have been erased.  These coherence issues are precisely what $\infty$ categories are designed to handle, so if a statement in an $\infty$ category paper implicitly uses a nontrivial coherence result from a late chapter of HA, then I really think it should be referenced. Otherwise, it's unclear where the work of upgrading the result went.

Comment: @Federico I don't think its right to say stable $\infty$ categories "solve the functoriality issues we encounter when we work with triangulated categories." They are just two different frameworks, and one is not inherently better than the other. I could just as well say "triangulated categories solve the problem of $\infty$-categories being difficult to learn about" or "Spanish solves the problem of English having all sorts of exceptions to every rule." I hope you see my point. Value judgments should not be used in such situations.

Comment: @Federico I would say the thing that is generally swept  under the rug is why two maps are the same. i.e. you claim that a map is an isomorphism because its a map between isomorphic objects. This problem clearly appears in the proof you presented, and it is the same to infinity categories as to 1-categories. It is just culturally excepted to ignore it in 1-categorical settings for basically no good reason. Once you note it, the difference between the theories become much smaller in practice I believe.

Comment: @S. carmeli  Obviously, it is a bad practice in both settings to assume that two different maps $f,g: X \to Y$ are the same. Mistakes of this sort have invalidated papers before!   But this cultural practice is more abusive when done in the $\infty$ setting, because it hides significantly more.  Maps are not simply equal or unequal, but the datum of equality needs to be specified, and shown to be consistent with all the other structure in play (which in turn requires introducing even more data).

Comment: As illustrated in this discussion, the details are often clear to experts.  But as $\infty$-categorical methods are (for good reason) adopted by a greater number of non-experts, I (as a novice) worry when these issues are brushed under the rug.

Comment: @DavidWhite I see your point. I wrote that phrase because of the way I think of $\infty$-categories and pretriangulated dg-categories, i.e. as frameworks which give us a functorial notion of cone. However, you are right, it is definitely just a choice of framework.

Comment: @PhilTosteson In abstract you're right, but in my experience in practice the adjustments one need to make the proof correct are not that different in the 1-categorical and in the ∞-categorical cases. Typically when you cannot write an ∞-categorical proof and you go back to the 1-categorical case to figure out what goes wrong, you'll find that your 1-categorical proof was also incomplete in the same way... And I am totally convinced that there are all sorts of (mostly unimportant) mistakes in the literature while using 1-categories.